# Disabling Hibernation AND DeepSleep mode on Retina Macbook Pro reduce battery life?

Tags: sleep-wake, macbook-pro, battery, hibernate

I am currently on 90%, HDMI connected to 2nd monitor, about 5-6 links open in Safari, terminal running (coding on python), Stickies, Messages, and Mail are running.

My battery has **2h** of remaining run-time before needing a charge !! I used to have about 6-8 hours about a month or two ago. I don't know if disabling hibernation mode and deep sleep mode have an impact on the battery's run-time ?

`pmset -g` returns :

```
Active Profiles:
Battery Power       -1*
AC Power        -1
Currently in use:
 standbydelay         7200
 standby              0
 halfdim              1
 hibernatefile        /var/vm/sleepimage
 darkwakes            0
 gpuswitch            2
 disksleep            0
 sleep                180 (sleep prevented by )
 autopoweroffdelay    14400
 hibernatemode        0
 autopoweroff         1
 ttyskeepawake        1
 displaysleep         5
 acwake               0
 lidwake              1
```

I have a retina macbook pro with SSD. I also usually keep the laptop charged 24hrs a day but discharge it to about 10% at least once or twice a week.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried looking at Activity Monitor? At least assuming you have OS X 10.9 Mavericks, it has a new Energy tab (in addition to the usual CPU, Memory, etc.) where you can see which apps are contributing the most to energy usage. And of course, there might be some hidden process consuming a lot of CPU time.

Also, it looks like your MacBook Pro has dual GPUs (Intel + Nvidia). Since you connected an external display, it's probably using the Nvidia GPU. In my experience this translates to a huge increase in power usage, so it wouldn't be unusual to have only 2h  of battery remaining. Even without an external display connected, some other app might be forcing a switch to the power-hungry Nvidia graphics; there's an app called [gfxCardStatus](http://gfx.io) which indicates which GPU is currently in use, and if it's the Nvidia one, which apps are to blame for activating it.